# In Pandas merge one colum value from other colum when both data type is object and only few values are null in first column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Data Frame is having two columns

```
df1
col1 col2
 A    A
 B    B
      C
      D
 E    E
 F    F
      G
      H
```

here both columns are object type, trying to merge value of column 2 with column 1 where column 1 value is null.
how to apply this for large dataset?I'm beginner for panads, trying to learn all the tricks here.

Comment: see this:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html

Comment: What do you mean, are you asking about `df['col1'].fillna(df['col2'])`?

Comment: i tried that but it is not working as i dont want to change any value in colum1 which is present not null, only those values in column 1 which are showing as empty, here both column data type is object.